# Disable past dates on tapku

Tags: tapku

Is there any way to disable the past dates or the desired dates in tapku calendar? Where in tapku, pressing the date occurs? I could not find it. Is it possible to set the minimum date, like in the datepicker?

Comment: Hi, I am looking for same thing. I need to disable all the dates before present date on TAPKU. Did you find any solution. If you did, then it will be really great if  you could share with me.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced problem like this so here i managed with below code

```
(void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)selectedDate
        {
         if([selectedDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending)
            {
                NSString *today=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];
                NSString *chooseday=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",selectedDate];
                NSArray *date1=[today componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
                NSArray *date2=[chooseday componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

                if([[date1 objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:[date2 objectAtIndex:0]])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Today date clicked");
                }
                else
                {

                    NSLog(@"Past date clicked");
                }
        }
        }
```